# How to execute child processes in order in C

Tags: c, process, fork

I have written a code in C to count lines words and characters in a file. Like the `wc` command. The code is below and works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
strcpy(result, s1);
strcat(result, s2);
return result;
} 

int countLines(char *f){
 FILE *file = fopen(f, "r");
int count = 0;
char ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
   if (ch == '\n')
       count++;
}
return count;
}

int countWords(char *f){
char buffer[1];
FILE *file = fopen(f, "r");
  int countW = 0;
  enum states { WSP, WRD };
  int state = WSP;
char last = ' '; 
 while (read(fileno(file),buffer,1) == 1 )
 {
 if ( buffer[0]== ' ' || buffer[0] == '\t' || buffer[0]=='\n' )
 {
    state = WSP;
 }
 else 
 {
    if ( state == WSP )
    {
       countW++;
    }
    state = WRD;
 }
  last = buffer[0];
}
return countW;
}

int countChars(char *f){
 FILE *file = fopen(f, "r");
int chars = 0;
char ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(file))){
     if (ch == EOF) break;
  chars++;
}
return chars;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 int lineCount = 0;
 int wordCount = 0;
 int charCount = 0;
 int n = 3;
 int i,status;
 int pids[3];
 char *theprogram = argv[0];
 char *thefile = argv[1];
 if ( argc !=2 )
 {
     printf( "Help: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
 }
 else{
     FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r");

   if(file == 0){
         char *sub = concat(theprogram, ": ");
         char *middle = concat(sub, thefile); 
         perror(middle);
   }
   else{
         for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             pids[i] = fork();
             if ( pids[i] < 0) { 
                perror("fork"); 
                exit(-1); 
            } else if (pids[i] == 0) { 
                if (i==0){
                        lineCount = countLines(argv[1]);
                        printf("This is child proccess %d, and the number of lines is %d\n", i+1, lineCount);
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if (i==1){ 
                        wordCount = countWords(argv[1]);
                        printf("This is child proccess %d, and the number of words is %d\n", i+1, wordCount);
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else if (i==2){
                        charCount += countChars(argv[1]);
                        printf("This is child proccess %d, and the number of characters is %d\n", i+1, charCount);
                        exit(0);
                    }
            } 
          }
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                wait(NULL);
            }
            return 0;      
            }
 } 
}
```

The problem i have is this:

The output is not always in order, like this:

```
//GOOD
This is child proccess 1, and the number of lines is 5
This is child proccess 2, and the number of words is 5
This is child proccess 3, and the number of characters is 159

//BAD
This is child proccess 1, and the number of lines is 5
This is child proccess 3, and the number of characters is 159
This is child proccess 2, and the number of words is 5
```

The third process ends before the second sometimes. How can i prevent this?

Comment: Why do you think it is undesirable to have them in different orders? Having results as quickly as possible seems like a good benefit.

Comment: John i have a requirement on the output, thats why. I know that having the result faster is better :)

Comment: OP, reread your requirements and make sure this is really what you are suppose to do.  It would make sense if you were to run multiple children and have them pipe the results back to the parent who would then print them.  It makes *no* sense to simultaneously run 3 children and then force them to be synchronous, particularly since you say you are unfamiliar with the mechanisms required to do so.  You could just as easily run one child after the next in your loop and get the same results with much less work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty method:

```
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) { 
            usleep(i*1000);  /* wait 1ms for child 1, 2ms for child 2,... */
            if (i==0){
                    lineCount = countLines(argv[1]);
                    printf("This is child proccess %d, and the number of lines is %d\n", i+1, lineCount);
                    exit(0);
                }
                else if (i==1){ 
                    wordCount = countWords(argv[1]);
                    printf("This is child proccess %d, and the number of words is %d\n", i+1, wordCount);
                    exit(0);
                }
                else if (i==2){
                    charCount += countChars(argv[1]);
                    printf("This is child proccess %d, and the number of characters is %d\n", i+1, charCount);
                    exit(0);
                }
        }
```

Another way would be by having the parent process to create three UNIX sockets and listen to all of them using `select()` or something like that. Childs would connect and write to the socket, exit, and then, parent process would print the information received in proper order.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i just need something quick.

Answer (score 0):

The forked processes will execute asynchronously to the main line code, so if you wanted them to happen in order, you need to use some kind of flag.  This could be a semaphore, mutex, or set a boolean value inside the if conditionals.

You would need to use a semaphore or mutex to protect susceptible data from asynchronous writes, but that's not an issue in this context.

Comment: I will try a boolean flag and see if that will help.Thanks for the suggestion. I am very new in C so I am not very familiar with semaphores.

Comment: None of these will work without using shared memory.  Mutex, semaphore, boolean, etc., in plain memory will still result in copies in the children that will not be reflected in the parent or other children.  You can get around this by using named semaphores or the like and opening them in the children but I seriously doubt that is the point of this exercise.

Comment: It's my understanding that shared memory is a model implemented by the operating system, rather than the process itself.  Is this inaccurate?

Comment: The OS implements it of course but in cases like this the process directly requests those services.

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use thread but not process, initializing some global variables and assign the variables value in the child thread. control the output in parent thread.