# Can't get my wordcount in C to work using child processes

Tags: c, fork, wait, pid

So my assignment is to create a word count program (again) using different child ids for each function.  I've got everything working pretty well, except for two small issues that I can't quite wrap my head around.

-when I pass a test document to my program ($./mywc2 testdoc) the command line will print the process twice:

colin@Colins-Samsung:~/Documents/Homework and slides$ ./mywc2 testdoc

This is child process 54473920, the number of lines is 4
This is child process 32744, the number of words is 21
This is child process 52242236, the number of characters is 77

This is child process 54473920, the number of lines is 4
This is child process 32744, the number of words is 21
This is child process 52242236, the number of characters is 77

-sometimes my processes are negative values (only line count and character count.)
I read that this is because the system doesn't want to initialize two new processes at a time, so I tried implementing a wait call, but I'm not sure how or when to put it in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int countLines(int childId)
{
getpid();
}
int countWords(int childId){
getpid();
}
int countChar(int childId){
getpid();
}

main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int pids[4];
int n=2;
int fd;
char buf[1000];
int charRead;
int nl=0;
int nw=0;
int nc=0;
int i;
int j;
int state=OUT;

int pid=fork();


fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY,0644);
if (fd==-1)
{ 
printf("errno=%d\n",errno);
perror("main");
}

//old mywc code block
charRead=read(fd, buf, 1001);
for (i=0; buf[i]; i++)
{
if(buf[i]!=' ')
{
    nc++;
}
if(buf[i]=='\n')
{
    nl++;
}
if(buf[i]==' '|| buf[i]=='\n' || buf[i]=='\t')
{
    state=OUT;
}
else if(state==OUT)
{
    state=IN;
    ++nw;
}
}
 close(fd);


//children block
//int pid=fork();

for(j=0;j<2;++j)
{
if(pid==0)
{
    if(j==0)
    {       
        countLines(j);

    }
    else if(j==1)
    {
        countWords(j);
        wait(100);
    }
    else if(j==2)
    {
        countChar(j);

}
}
else if(pid!=0)
{
    perror("fork");
    abort();
}
}
wait(10);


printf("This is child process %d, the number of lines is %d\n",pids[0], nl);
printf("This is child process %d, the number of words is %d\n",pids[1], nw);
printf("This is child process %d, the number of characters is %d\n",pids[2], nc);
printf("\n");
close(fd);


}
```

Comment: I don't see where you set pids.

Comment: I'm not sure why it works, but if I change the for loop to implement the pids[] array, it will print 0 for the first two child ids, and then an actual process for the character count.  

After going back and changing some brackets though (in the original I posted) the program works as desired.  Is it ok that my process ids are negative some of the time?

Comment: You're not capturing the output of `getpid` and you have other very basic mistakes here. Look again at whatever source you are using to learn how to use multiple processes.

Comment: Deja-vu
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449276/how-to-execute-child-processes-in-order-in-c